# Print map in arcgis javascript api

Tags: arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript, printing

I'm developing an application, and I'm using arcgis javascript api, I'm trying to print the map using Print() object, but when pressing on the print button, it syas printing, and after amount of time, it says time out, and didn't print anything, this happens when I added the dynamicLayers to the map, what's wrong?

Comment: Have you opened the browser's developers tool and examined what results you're getting in the console?

Comment: I'm getting that, I have to enable cors.

Comment: maybe because the coordinate system of the layers are different from the coordinate system of the map, if it is, what is the solution?

Comment: Is there a error event fired? If so what does the error object returned say? https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/jsapi/print-amd.html#event-error

Comment: Do you have secured map service added to your map?